# How to end execution of a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, return, block

I thought blocks were like anonymous functions.

But when I tried to end the execution of a block using `return` keyword, I think it triggered a return in the scope in which the block was defined in. Is that how they work?

If so, how can I end the execution of a block, in a way that does not trigger a return in the outer scope?

Comment: Already asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402757/how-to-break-out-from-a-ruby-block

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The keyword is `next`, not `break`. Break seems to be specific for the `each` method.

Answer (score -10):

To exit a block or loop use the `break` keyword.

`return` will exit a method.

Comment: break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)