# How do next, break, redo, and return work from the block caller's perspective?

Tags: ruby

Because Ruby relies so heavily on the use of blocks for iteration (`while` and `for` loops do exist in Ruby, but they're very rarely used by Ruby developers in practice) Ruby allows some keywords often associated with loops in other languages, such as `break`, `next`, and `redo`, to be used inside of blocks. `return` in Ruby also returns from the method the block is inside, which is consistent with the behavior of a loop, instead of from the block itself as functional programming languages do. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402764/1157054) explains those behaviors quite nicely.

Now what I'm wondering is how this behavior works **from the block caller's perspective** (by block caller, I mean the method the block is being called from, as opposed to the method the block is defined in). For some of these keywords it's pretty self-explanatory (e.g. `next` simply returns from the block, and `redo` calls the block again with the same arguments), but for others the exact behavior is unclear to me. Specifically...

When I call `break` from a block, does execution immediately get handed to the point after the block is defined? If I have some post-iteration cleanup steps to perform from within the iterator method, do they get completely skipped? E.g.:

```
def iterate
  setup
  1.upto(5) do |x|
    yield x
  end
  cleanup # Does this get called? If not, how can I ensure that it does?
end

iterate do |x|
  puts x # Prints 1
  break # Break prevents further looping, somehow
end
# Execution continues here after break
```

What about with `return`? I would assume it has similar behavior to that of `break` in this context (whatever that behavior may be). Is that indeed the case?

What's even more confusing though is that Ruby blocks can be captured as method parameters and converted to Proc objects. These objects can then be called from *anywhere*, even outside the method that the block was originally defined in:

```
def get_proc(&block)
  block
end

def get_iterator_proc
  p = get_proc do |x| # Block is defined here...
    puts x
    break
  end
  # ...so `break` makes execution continue here...

  do_other_stuff

  return p
end

p = get_iterator_proc

p.call # ...even though the block isn't actually called until here?
```

And again, the same goes for `return`. What does it actually return from in this context? How do these keywords *really* work?

Comment: Did you check - http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Oh, so they're actually not keywords but rather instance methods on `Object`? That's interesting...

Comment: No they are *keywords*.... Look this http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/

Comment: @ArupRakshit Oh, I see. "Yes, I KNOW that they aren‘t methods. I‘ve just put them in that format to produce the familiar RDoc output." Kind of confusing... Is there any similar documentation for Ruby 2.x?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I just read those docs as you suggested, and they only seem to address how the keywords work from the block's perspective, not from the block caller's perspective. They also do not address the specific examples I gave at all.

Comment: Again for you - https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_0/NEWS#L170

Comment: There is a very good blog post.. Just n this topic.. But I am not able to get it now.. forgot where I read about this.. :-) I could answer.. But it is too late here.. And you asked a lots in together although.. If it is short, I could jump on it.. Wait may be someone is writing for you. :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yeah, I was considering splitting this up into 2 separate questions (one about the case where there's extra stuff going on in the iterator after the break or return, and one about the case where the block gets executed after the method it's defined in returns). The stuff in here does seem pretty closely related though, so idk...

Comment: @Ajedi32 have you come to an answer for your question? If so, please post your findings and links below.

Comment: @HunterStevens Sorry, no I haven't. In retrospect though, I could probably figure this out by poking around in IRB a bit...

Comment: @Ajedi32 I asked because this is a very interesting question, and I would like to know more. Probably not suitable for StackOverflow, but would be a great essay or blog post.

Answer (score 1):

```
def iterate
  setup
  1.upto(5) do |x|
    yield x
  end
  cleanup # Does this get called? If not, how can I ensure that it does?
end

iterate do |x|
  puts x # Prints 1
  break # Break prevents further looping, somehow
end
# Execution continues here after break
```

> cleanup # Does this get called?

Yes. However, if there is an exception, then exception handling takes precedence.

> cleanup #  If not, how can I ensure that it does?

You can use [ensure](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-ensure) without a rescue, for when there is an exception.

> break # Break prevents further looping, somehow

I'd *suspect* it uses `throw` as that is how `Enumerable` works.

> What about with return? I would assume it has similar behavior to that of break in this context (whatever that behavior may be). Is that indeed the case?

It depends on the context. You might get a `LocalJumpError: unexpected return` or it might work as a `break`

```
def get_proc(&block)
  block
end

def get_iterator_proc
  p = get_proc do |x| # Block is defined here...
    puts x
    break
  end
  # ...so `break` makes execution continue here...
```

Effectively, but there is a subtle difference. It is more like your first example.

```
def get_proc(&block)
  block
  # ...so `break` makes execution continue here...
end

def get_iterator_proc
  p = get_proc do |x| # Block is defined here...
    puts x
    break
  end
  # get_proc returned here (after assigning to p)
```

Remember, `get_proc` is just a function call with a special syntax to pass functions.

if you had

```
def get_proc(&block)
  block
  7
end
```

Then in `get_iterator_proc` `p` would be `7` (And we'd be sad that 7 didn't have a `call` method )