# ruby aequivalent to abort that does not exit irb

Tags: ruby

In the method below I'm using `abort` to prematurely end the action if a given condition is met.

However, `abort` also throws the user out of IRB.

Is there something else besides abort the will end or break the method, but not kick the user out of irb.

Thanks.

```
def contrary
  if @quantity.label  == "particular"
    abort("There is no contrary for this type of propostion. Try subcontrary")
  end
  quality = @quality.opposite

  if @truthvalue
    truthvalue = !@truthvalue
  elsif !@truthvalue
    truthvalue = "unknown"
  end

  contrary = Proposition.new(@quantity, @subject, quality, @predicate, truthvalue)
  return contrary
end
```

Comment: Haven't used ruby in awhile, but break or next should work?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402757/how-to-break-out-from-a-ruby-block

Comment: but I do like sending a message with `abort("this doesn't work, trying something else")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `raise` instead of `abort`. `abort` terminates your program, by design, whereas `raise` throws an exception that is caught by IRB's evaluator.

Answer (score 1):

A `return` doesn't have to be the final statement in a method, nor does it have to return a value (it can return `nil`).

So having the following as the first line of your method should achieve what you're looking for:

`return if @quantity.label == "particular"`

If you want to output a message first:

```
if @quantity.label == "particular"
  puts "There is no contrary for this type of propostion. Try subcontrary"
  return
end
```