# How to return a value early from a Ruby block?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write some Ruby code that will return a value from a block that is passed to a function. I don't want the block to exit early, I just want to avoid writing too many `if` statements in order to implicitly return the value.

How can I rewrite this to return the value early?

This works:

```
def my_method
  my_array.delete_if do |item|
    if item.removed?
      true
    elsif item == 'something else'
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

This won't work because you can't call return in a block:

```
def my_method
  my_array.delete_if do |item|
    return true if item.removed?
    return true if item == 'something else'

    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the intent to remove items from the array if either (a) calling `#removed?` on the item returns true or (b) the item is equivalent to `something else`? Are you able to add a method to the class that `item` belongs to?

Comment: The code in the example was just to demonstrate the scenario, I am actually working with an array of strings, not objects. I'm really just trying to figure out how to return the value without exiting the block.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11678342/479863) to the duplicate seems  to be what you're looking for.